# Fermat's Last Theorem for Amateurs, two questions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, notation

Looking at Ribenboim's book, page 2.

First question:  What is the difference in the notational use of $X, Y, Z$ versus $x, y, z$?

Second question:  Why is this true:  "If $n$ is odd then $X^n + Y^n = Z^n$ has a non-trivial solution if and only if $X^n + Y^n + Z^n = 0$ has a non-trivial solution."?

Comment: 1) no idea without the book. 2) replace $Z\to -Z$.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I thought it was for #2 but didn't want to assume I saw the whole picture.

Answer (score 0):

Upper-case letters are more variable than lower-case.  The equation $X^n+Y^n=Z^n$ is to show the relationship among the variables.  The lower-case letters $x,y,z$ indicate a specific solution.

$X$ is an indeterminate and $x$ is a number that gets plugged into it.

But really, you can ignore the difference.

Comment: I disagree. "More variable" makes no mathematical sense.

Comment: @EthanBolker  But language is notoriously not-mathematical.   When we integrate and write $+C$, we call that a "constant".  What?  Is it a variable constant or a constant variable?   I'm marking, informally, that $X$ is not a specific value and $x$ is.  $x$ is less variable.

Comment: Ribenboim (and many others) use uppercase characters when writing an "abstract" equation, and lowercase characters when describing the numbers (usually integers) that satisfy the equation — _i.e._, $x$, $y$, and $z$ are integers satisfying the equation $X^2+Y^2=Z^2$.

Comment: Thank you.  I looked hard at the way he used upper and lower cases.  It seemed like he was using upper case for integers and lower case for a subset, like non-zero integers or non-negative integers.  But I think your responses make more sense.

Comment: Maybe it would be good to hedge your first sentence a little, because it might not be good for a new student to take it as gospel. That is, something like "some authors use upper case letters as "more variable" variables."  I agree that it looks like a plausible explanation for what Ribenboim is doing.

Answer (score 0):

First question. There is no difference. Ribenboim just chose upper case.

Second question. When $n$ is odd, $(-z)^n = -z^n$. So if $(x,y,z)$ satisfies
$$
x^n + y^n = z^n
$$
then
$$
x^n + y^n + (-z)^n = 0
$$
so one of those equations has an integral solution just when the other does. You can study either.

Comment: Actually, Ribenboim uses both upper and lower case.  If you go to Amazon you can look at page 2 and see what the OP's question refers to.